# Good fdisk output for backup image but can't mount to loop device even when using offset

Tags: mount, backup, dd

I've recently created a backup file for my Ubuntu 16.04.4 server using `dd` in order to prepare for migrating to a larger SSD. I want to mount the backup image through a separate Ubuntu VM running on my local machine to check that the backup worked as expected.

Attempting to loop mount as follows:

> mount -o loop image ~/mnt/serverTest

Returns the following error:

> mount: /root/mnt/serverTest: can't read superblock on /dev/loop6

Examining the image using fdisk as follows:

> fdisk -l image

Gives the following output:

```
Disk image: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3ed8245

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
image1     *     2048 62914526 62912479  30G 83 Linux
```

This looks pretty promising to me - it seems as though the backup image has been generated correctly - and I even attempted the loop mount with an offset (512*2048=1048576) as follows:

> mount -o loop,offset=1048576 image ~/mnt/serverTest

But the exact same error stating that the superblock can't be read comes back.

Finally, examining the image file with badblocks reports no corrupted blocks, however executing `fsck.ext4 image` reports a bad magic number in super-block and states that a dos partition table has been found.

**TL;DR** - Mount errors and fsck.ext4 output seem to suggest something wrong with the backup image, but fdisk output looks alright. What am I missing?

Comment: Just to confirm part of what you seem to have already figured out, and maybe clarify some that you haven’t: Commands like `mount` and `fsck` operate on a filesystem, which typically resides in a partition.  Your backup is a disk image that contains a partition table and one partition.  So `fsck.ext4 image` *shouldn’t* work.  AFAIK, the `mount` command *should* have worked with `offset=`; I don’t know why it didn’t.  What happens if you say `offset=1024KiB` or `1MiB`?  Also, try `2048KiB` and `2MiB` (just in case `fdisk` is reporting the partition start and end points in 1K blocks).

Comment: Cheers for the response G-Man. Your clarification on fsck makes sense. Passing in a disk image when fsck is expecting a file system shouldn't work.
I tried all your suggested modifications to the offset parameter but unfortunately none of them made any difference - still the same superblock error.